# How to access parameter of Callable Future after execution?

Tags: java, future

I create some async tasks using `Future` and `Callable<>`.
Problem: if an `Exception` occurs during the async execution, I need to access the parameter that was used to build the callable. But how?

Example:

```
List<Callable<Response> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
taks.add(() -> sendRequest(req));

futures = executor.invokeAll(tasks);

for (future : futures) {
    try {
        Response rsp = future.get();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        //problem: I need to access req.getType() value of the req Object here. But How?
    }
}
```

Like: I want to collect all request values from `req.getType()`, so I know which async requests failed. And return them in an error message to the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the question has been thoroughly answered I wanted to contribute a few other ideas, and perhaps illustrate some of those already discussed.

#### About Order of Results and Blocking

One interesting aspect of submitting a set of tasks to be run in separate threads is the fact that we can no longer control the order in which those tasks will be completed. Some tasks may run first, or even those that run first might take longer than others to complete.

Now consider this:

```
List<Future<Integer>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
futures.add(executor.submit(() -> doTaskWith(100));
futures.add(executor.submit(() -> doTaskWith(200));

for(future: futures) {
   future.get(); //Uh oh, blocking here!
}
```

In the example above if our first future takes 30 seconds to complete, and the second one takes only 15 seconds; then we actually blocked for 30 seconds to start processing the results, but the first result was done 15 seconds before.

The point is that, we could improve things if we could start aggregating the results as soon as they become available.

#### Using an ExecutionService

One way to deal with this kind of problem is by using an [ExecutorCompletionService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) to submit the tasks and control the results.

For example:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
ExecutorCompletionService<Double> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);

completionService.submit(() -> doTaskWith(100));
completionService.submit(() -> doTaskWith(200));

Future<Double> future = completionService.take(); //whichever finishes first
```

The `ExecutorCompletionService` works like a queue, and once a task is done, whichever that task may be, we can [poll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html#poll()) it or [take](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html#take()) it out of the queue and get its results.

#### Propose Solution 1: Using a Map of Futures

Imagine that we have a function to calculate the square root of an integer:

```
static double sqrt(int n) {
    if(n > 0) {
        return Math.sqrt(n);
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid integer: " + n);
}
```

So, now imagine that we want to submit a bunch of integers to get their square root calculated.

For example:

```
Map<Future<Double>, Integer> tasks = Stream.of(4, 25, 36, 49, -5)
      .collect(toMap(n -> completionService.submit(() -> sqrt(n)),
      Function.identity()));
```

So, we take every integer from the stream and create a `Callable<Integer>` out of every one of them (i.e. `() -> sqrt(n)`). Every callable gets the square root of the contextual integer `n`. Then we pass that callable to our completion service and get a future out it (i.e. `completionService.submit(callable)`). Then we make that returned `future` the key of our map, and the integer `n` the value of that key in the map, which is what we see in the returned object (i.e. `Map<Future<Double>, Integer> tasks`)

Now we have the set of futures (from our submitted tasks) as keys, and the integers used to obtain those futures as the values.

Now we can do:

```
Set<Future<Double>> futures = new HashSet<>(tasks.keySet());
Set<Future<Double>> failures = new LinkedHashSet<>();

while (!futures.isEmpty()) {
    try {
        Future<Double> future = completionService.take();
        int n = tasks.get(future); //original value of n
        double squareRoot = future.get(); //result of task
        System.out.printf("The square root of %d is %f%n", n, squareRoot);
    }
    catch (ExecutionException e) {
        Integer n = tasks.get(future); //original value of n
        System.err.printf("Failure to obtain square root of %d: %s%n", n, e.getMessage());
        failures.add(future);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //TODO: handle interruption somehow, perhaps logging partial results?
    }
    finally {
        futures.remove(future);
    }
}

if(!failures.isEmpty()) {
    //TODO you may want to do do something about the failures you got
}
```

Since the future is the key in our map, when the `completionService` reports that a given future is ready, then we can easily just look up that future in our map and get the original value of `n` that we submitted to be processed (i.e. `int n = tasks.get(future)`).

#### Propose Solution 2: Contextual Exceptions

Another way to deal with the problem is by making sure that the exceptions you throw contain all the contextual details that you need to get your original request object back.

For example, we could change our `sqrt` code as follows:

```
static double sqrt(int n) {
    if(n > 0) {
        return Math.sqrt(n);
    }
    throw new InvalidIntegerException(n);
}

static class InvalidIntegerException extends RuntimeException {

    private final Integer n;

    InvalidIntegerException(int n) {
        super("Invalid integer:  " + n);
        this.n = n;
    }

    public Integer getInteger() {
        return n;
    }
}
```

Now if we fail to calculate a square root, we will get back a `InvalidIntegerException` that contains the original value that failed to be process. That exception can give us that original value back.

That original exception will be wrapped in a `ExecutionException` by the executor service.

So, now we could do something like this:

```
Future<Double> future = completionService.take();
try {
    System.out.printf("The square root of %d is %f%n", tasks.get(future), future.get());
}
catch (ExecutionException e) {
    if(e.getCause() != null && e.getCause() instanceof InvalidIntegerException) {
        Integer n = ((InvalidIntegerException) e.getCause()).getInteger();
        System.err.println("Failure to calculate the square root of: " + n);
    }
```

}

I kind of prefer the first solution because I don't have to make any assumptions on the type of exceptions being thrown, which makes the code easier to maintain. Perhaps others can comment on the pros and cons of every strategy.

Comment: I'd love to see a less boilerplate solution on concept no. 2. Think of having to return a combination of original and custom value with the exception. Just some value that should be used by the exception handler. Then there is no chance in mapping the custom value beforehand.

Answer (score 7):

According to [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)), every conforming `ExecutorService` will:

> @return a list of Futures representing the tasks, in the same
> sequential order as produced by the iterator for the
> given task list, each of which has completed

So considering that you had a list of tasks at the start, every `Future` object with a failure that you encounter at index `i` at the list will correspond to `Callable` task at index `i` in tasks list:

```
List<Request> requests = // obtain request
List<Callable<Response>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
requests.forEach(req -> tasks.add(() -> sendRequest(req)));

List<Future<Response>> futures = executor.invokeAll(tasks);

for (int i = 0; i < futures.size(); i++) {
  Future<Response> future = futures.get(i);
  try {
    Response rsp = future.get();
    handleResponse(rsp);
  } catch (ExecutionException e) {
    Request req = requests.get(i); // this is request parameter for send request at index i, assuming your Service does not violate its contract
    handleRequestFailure(req, e.getCause());
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a nice approach, like it. Better than my idea of keeping track manually...

Comment: @GhostCat, it sort of is, but it relies on services keeping to contract (which occasionally is not true), and it requires a list of requests. If we would've had a `Set` of requests, it won't be as easy.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov But then you could just convert the set to a list first and pass that to `invokeAll`. Problem is only if you don't have all reqeuests beforehand.

Comment: I know alll of the requests before executing them async, so yes that would be a possibility. Though I hoped it would be easier/less boilerplate to achieve.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker, if you don't have them right away, you'd have two calls to `invokeAll` with similar rules. That method doesn't return unless all tasks are done, so at that point to use to add more tasks in same list.

Comment: A minor mistake in code, instead of using future.get() to retrieve the result from the future, it should use futures.get(i).get() to obtain the result from the specific future at index i.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind: that `ExecutionException` you are catching **wraps** around an exception that got thrown by the `Callable` implementation.

So if you want to have details in that exception - well, *you* have to make sure that this exception that gets thrown and wrapped contains the required information.

Alternatively, you have to actually track which Future belongs to which "input parameter". Like creating a `Map<Future, Request>` that you **fill** while *pushing* the Callable objects into the executor.

Comment: Ok so I have to create a `WrapResponseException(Response rsp)` that is to be thrown inside `sendRequest()` if I want to access the params?

Comment: No. What I mean is: code inside the callable is throwing at you. If you want data about the context, it needs to be included there. Alternatively, you have to *track* the futures when you *create* them; see my updated answer.